# Filtering phone numbers REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a MySQL query to find 10 digit phone numbers that start with +1

```
SELECT blah
FROM table
WHERE phone REGEXP'^\\+[1]{1}[0-9]{10}$'
```

How can I filter this REGEXP further to only search certain 3 digit area codes? (ie. International 10 digit phone numbers who share US number format)

I tried using the IN clause ie. `IN('+1809%','+1416%')` but ended up with error in syntax

```
WHERE phone REGEXP'^\\+[1]{1}[0-9]{10}$' IN('+1809%','+1416%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [grouping construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with an [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) here, like

```
REGEXP '^\\+1(809|416)[0-9]{7}$' 
             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Just subtract 3 from 10 to match the trailing digits. Note that in MySQL versions prior to 8.x, you cannot use non-capturing groups, you may only use capturing ones.

Also, `[1]{1}` pattern is equal to `1` because each pattern is matched exactly once by default (i.e. `{1}` is always redundant) and it makes littel sense to use a character class `[...]` with just one single symbol inside, it is meant for two or more, or to avoid escaping some symbols, but `1` does not have to be escaped as it is a word char, so the square brackets are totally redundant here.